# bootstrap datepicker is not showing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

So I'm trying to get a `datepicker` that shows only the years; after doing some researches I used `eyecon bootsrap datepicker`but it doesn't even show up even though I tried every way possible to implement it, and the `css` files and `js` are imported correctly.
Been struggeling for a couple of days now.

here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/datepicker.css" />
```

js part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            format: " yyyy",
            viewMode: "years", 
            minViewMode: "years"
            });

});
```

Html part:

```
<input size="16" type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

Result:
a text field and nothing when I click.

**Update:**
I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xbsav244/1/) and I noticed it only works when bootstrap is `onDomready` and doesn't when `onLoad`. How to translate that in code? maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Are you referencing Bootstrap js file too?

Comment: And ***which*** datepicker are you using? Could be a useful information, don't think so?

Comment: i'm using the http://www.eyecon.ro one

Comment: I don't see a reference to jQuery, are you missing it?

Comment: it's the first one, u missed it :)

Comment: No, that's jQuery UI, it's a different library.

Comment: We don't have enough information. A standalone example [works perfectly](http://www.bootply.com/57nAPKPeSm). You must have something else interfering. Are there errors in your browser console ?

Comment: nothing is showing that is the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it working using the same code but with different version of bootstrap datepicker which is `eternicode` one. Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the reference to jQuery, add this line before the other js files:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: maybe, but still nothing changes

Comment: If I take the code you posted and add this line it works for me